# Seg fault when assigning a string in a struct

Tags: c++

```
struct Person {
    int age;
    string name;
};

int main() {
    struct Person* firstPerson;

    firstPerson = new Person();

    firstPerson->age = 23;
    firstPerson->name = "John Doe";

    cout << firstPerson->age << " " << firstPerson->name;
    return 0;
}
```

When I do the above it all works well and there is no seg fault. However if I change the above to

```
int main() {
    struct Person* firstPerson;

    firstPerson = static_cast<struct Person*>(malloc(sizeof(struct Person)));
    firstPerson->age = 23;
    cout << firstPerson->age;
    firstPerson->name = "John Doe";

    return 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: It would help if you posted the definitions of House and Person.  Normally, objects in C++ are created with new.  Why are you calling malloc and doing a cast?   firstPerson = new Person() would be the normal thing to do.  I'd need to go re-read the standard to know if calling malloc is legal in C++.

Comment: I know that malloc is not a standard way in c++ but I am trying to mix code and see if it works...

Comment: _"I am trying to mix code"_ - Forget about trying to do all this tricky stuff. Concentrate on learning the language and how to use it _effectively_. Once you've done that you'll realize how futile and pointless that type of coding is.

Comment: I realized that if you use string inside a struct and dont initialize ( due to malloc) by providing a constructor than it will result in  seg fault.

Comment: There is no need for any new or malloc here. `Person firstPerson;` is sufficient to create the object.

Comment: Yes I understand what you are saying but I am trying to use malloc to assign the string a value.....Is it doable? I know I am mixing c and c++

Comment: If you don't know c++ and c well enough to know that you shouldn't mix them then take our advice and don't mix them.

Comment: If you change name to be "char *name" then your program will work (probably, I didn't try it), because it will be standard C, even if you use a C++ compiler.  "string" is a C++ object.

Answer (score 3):

You can only create POD structs using `malloc` alone. malloc only allocates memory, but complex classes need to be initialized as well. Use new to allocate structs containing more complex (non-POD) data types (as `string`). If you really need to use malloc you can use placement new operator:

```
void* foo = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
firstPerson= new(foo) Person();
```

Placement new operator executes initialization (construction) of given type on already allocated memory block.

Comment: What is POD refer to?

Comment: @zeloran http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure

Answer (score 2):

Use `new` to construct an object, not `malloc`:

```
Person* firstPerson = new Person();
```

`new` allocates memory *and* constructs the object there. `malloc` only allocates memory - you have *no* object there only *raw* memory.

Comment: `malloc` will work in this case because `Person` is C-compatible.

Comment: But i have a string inside the struct. That is where the problem is...Can you suggest how to get around it?

Comment: @chris since when `std::string` is POD or, as you call it, C-compatible?

Comment: @zeloran if you *must* use `malloc`, use something like: `void * raw_mem = malloc(sizeof(Person));`, *then* use *placement* `new`: `Person* firstPerson = new(raw_mem) Person();` - which will construct the object there.

Comment: @j_kubik, It [used to be](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25798231/2) `const char *`.

Comment: @chris - sorry, I don't track edit history.

Comment: @chris sorry too, was just trying to give you the best answer I could off the top of my head...